# Retrieve data from YAML and convert each value as its own array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have this in my yml file

```
members: 
  - id: 1
    name: Sam
  - id: 18
    name: tom
```

After retrieving data from this file in a rails application I want to convert it to an array.
for example

```
id=[1,18]
name=[sam,tom]
```

how can I achieve this?

Currently This is how I am retrieving the data.

`yml = YAML.load_file("mem.yml")`

And this is how i get my data

```
[{"id":1, "name":"Sam"},{"id":18, "name":"tom"}]
```

if I use `yml["members"][1]["id"]` I get the first id.

I also tried writing id and name separately like below. This does give me what I want when I use `yml["id"]`but I don't want to use it because of its readability. BTW my data is static.

```
id:
 - 1
 - 18
name:
 - Sam
 - tom
```

Comment: `ids = yml['members'].map { |member| member['id'] }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below:

```
yml = [{"id":1, "name":"Sam"},{"id":18, "name":"tom"}]

result = {}.tap do |result|
           yml.each do |hash|       # Iterate over array of hashes on parsed input from YAML file
             hash.each do |key, value|      # Iterate over each keys in the hash 
               result[key] ||= []           
               result[key] << value         # Append element in the array
             end
           end
         end
```

This will return the `result` as a hash:

```
{:id=>[1, 18], :name=>["Sam", "tom"]}
```

You can access the ids and names as

```
result[:id]   # [1, 18]
result[:name] # ["Sam", "tom"]
```